# Openlink Virtuoso SPARQL OFFSET and LIMIT behavior

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

The following SPARQL query returns 20 results. I was expecting 10 given the `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX dbpedia:<http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?person_id ?person2_id
WHERE {
    {
        SELECT DISTINCT ?person_id ?person2_id WHERE {
          ?person rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Person .
          ?person2 rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Person .
          ?person ?link ?person2 .
          ?person dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?person_id .
          ?person2 dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?person2_id .
          FILTER (?link = dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink) .
        } ORDER BY ?link
    }
} OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10
```

I execute the code in the SPARQL endpoint of an OpenLink Virtuoso Server.

What is the problem with the query?

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  If you've said "LIMIT 10", you should only get 10 results.  However, the OFFSET is meaningless without an ORDER BY on the query.  (I know there's an ORDER BY in the subquery, but that doesn't matter for the outer query.)

Comment: Should be reported on the Virtuoso mailing list but with additional information like the version of Virtuoso and maybe some more stats.

Comment: As @AKSW suggests, version details are vital to a useful response. Also, Virtuoso-specific resources are often best for Virtuoso-specific questions; e.g., the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/), the [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). (ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to send specific questions through the channels you are suggesting

Answer (score 0):

The clause that makes the query behave weird is `ORDER BY ?link`. Replacing it with `ORDER BY ?person_id` all works as expected. It makes still no sense to me but I am a newbie using SPARQL too.

Answer (score 0):

@jordipala said

> The clause that makes the query behave weird is `ORDER BY ?link`. Replacing it with `ORDER BY ?person_id` all works as expected. It makes still no sense to me but I am a newbie using SPARQL too.

Part of the issue is that the `?link` values aren't string literals, though they may appear to be if you include that variable in the `SELECT` clauses.  (Also note that the `?link` values are all the same for these solutions, so you definitely need to put something else into the `ORDER BY` such that it does the desired job of preventing both duplicate solutions and omitted solutions.)

Also, counterintuitively given the `?link` datatype, the numeric-appearing `person_id` and `person2_id` are not typed as numbers -- they're strings, unless you force their datatype.

If you simply change `?link` to `str(?link)` in the `ORDER BY`, the query will deliver the desired 10 rows -- and you may note that all the `?link` values are identical! -- and if you include `person_id` and `person2_id` in the `ORDER BY` (done in my following links by using the ordinals of the `SELECT` variables, because of where and how I've coerced the datatypes), you'll get more useful output, as in [this query](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+owl%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+xsd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia-owl%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpprop%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT+%3FpersonID%0D%0A+++++++%3Fperson2ID%0D%0A+++++++%3Flink%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++SELECT+DISTINCT+%28+xsd%3Ainteger%28str%28%3Fperson_id%29%29++AS+%3FpersonID++%29+%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++%28+xsd%3Ainteger%28str%28%3Fperson2_id%29%29+AS+%3Fperson2ID+%29%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Flink%0D%0A++++++++WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++++++%3Fperson+rdf%3Atype+dbpedia-owl%3APerson+.%0D%0A++++++++++%3Fperson2+rdf%3Atype+dbpedia-owl%3APerson+.%0D%0A++++++++++%3Fperson+%3Flink+%3Fperson2+.%0D%0A++++++++++%3Fperson+dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageID+%3Fperson_id+.%0D%0A++++++++++%3Fperson2+dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageID+%3Fperson2_id+.%0D%0A++++++++++FILTER+%28%3Flink+%3D+dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageWikiLink%29+.%0D%0A++++++++%7D+ORDER+BY+3+1+2%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A%7D+OFFSET+10+LIMIT+10%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on) and [these results](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+owl%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+xsd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia-owl%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpprop%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT+%3FpersonID%0D%0A+++++++%3Fperson2ID%0D%0A+++++++%3Flink%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++SELECT+DISTINCT+%28+xsd%3Ainteger%28str%28%3Fperson_id%29%29++AS+%3FpersonID++%29+%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++%28+xsd%3Ainteger%28str%28%3Fperson2_id%29%29+AS+%3Fperson2ID+%29%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Flink%0D%0A++++++++WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++++++%3Fperson+rdf%3Atype+dbpedia-owl%3APerson+.%0D%0A++++++++++%3Fperson2+rdf%3Atype+dbpedia-owl%3APerson+.%0D%0A++++++++++%3Fperson+%3Flink+%3Fperson2+.%0D%0A++++++++++%3Fperson+dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageID+%3Fperson_id+.%0D%0A++++++++++%3Fperson2+dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageID+%3Fperson2_id+.%0D%0A++++++++++FILTER+%28%3Flink+%3D+dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageWikiLink%29+.%0D%0A++++++++%7D+ORDER+BY+3+1+2%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A%7D+OFFSET+10+LIMIT+10%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on)